# How does the speed of WriteString compare to other languages?

Tags: export, files-and-directories, performance-tuning

I'm doing something where the most sensible approach seems to be to open a file and write to it as I process data from some large tables. Old school. While testing the program, I remembered the low level write statements I use to use to do this kind of thing in FORTRAN and how fast they seemed to be, and I wondered how `WriteString` compared, so I did a little test. It took 10.875 seconds to write 1,000,000 records with record number, "Hello World." That seems pretty fast, but how does that compare to other languages? I use only Mathematica these days so I can't easily do any comparisons.

```
funit = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "writetest.csv"];
Timing[Do[WriteString[funit, i, ",Hello World\n"];, {i, 1, 1000000}]]

(*  {10.875000, Null}  *)
```

Comment: Can you please post plain code and not an image.

Comment: You can probably do a little bit better with `Scan[WriteString[funit, #, ",Hello World\n"] &, 
  Range[1000000]]`

Comment: Probably faster, unless you need to write as it happens, to build list of outputs and fire it out in one go.

Comment: Mathematica has much worse performance here not because of write commands, but the loop (and perhaps type conversion). I have tried `Timing[(StringJoin@ConstantArray["Hello World\n", 1000000]) >> "/tmp/writetest2.csv"]`, which takes less than a second. But I haven't found a fast way to output the line number at the same time.

Comment: I'd like to see more of these types of questions :)  thanks @George

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: I thought to summarize all results in a small table, to make it easy to see. Thanks for george2079 for adding the C++ and Python results (may be I'll do Java later)
results in seconds. Lower is better. Notice that Fortran was run on a virtual machine (VBox).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Grid[{
  {"Mathematica", "Matlab (elapsed)", Column[{"Fortran", "Virtual machine)"}, 
     Alignment -> Center], "C++", "Python"},      
  {Grid[{
     {"AbsoluteTiming", "Timing", "Command Line"},
     {6, 8.9, 7.3}}
    ],

   9.2,

   Grid[{
     {"elasped", "CPU_TIMING"},
     {0.5, 0.25}
     }],

   0.06, 0.44}      
  }, Frame -> All]
```

**Original answer**

I am no expert in any of these, so there might be better way to do this in Matlab and Fortran. But this is what I get. All on same PC, windows 7. The linux is on a VM installed on top of windows. The VM is 32 bit Linux mint.

### Mathematica 9.01, 64 bit windows 7

```
funit = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "writetest.csv"];
Timing[Do[WriteString[funit, i, ",Hello World\n"];, {i, 1, 1000000}]]
Close[funit]
(* {5.912438, Null} *)
(* {5.928038, Null} *)
(* {6.006038, Null} *)
```

Version using `AbsoluteTiming` based on comment below

```
funit = OpenWrite[NotebookDirectory[] <> "writetest.csv"];
AbsoluteTiming[Do[WriteString[funit, i, ",Hello World\n"];, {i, 1, 1000000}]]
Close[funit]
{9.009644, Null}
{8.890629, Null}
{8.866126, Null}
```

### Matlab 2013a, 32bit, on windows 7 64 bit

```
%w.m file
if(~isdeployed)
  cd(fileparts(which(mfilename)));
end

fid = fopen('writetest.csv','W'); %notice, W and not w, faster
tic;
for i=1:1000000
    fprintf(fid,'%s\n','Hello World');
end
toc
fclose(fid);
```

result

```
EDU>> w
Elapsed time is 9.321961 seconds.
EDU>> w
Elapsed time is 9.265512 seconds.
EDU>> w
Elapsed time is 9.297699 seconds.
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### gfortran version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)

```
>gfortran -v
Target: i686-linux-gnu
gcc version 4.8.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 

program w
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: out = 10
    integer :: i 
    real :: start, finish
    call cpu_time(start)
    open(out, file='writetest.csv', status='replace', action='write')

    DO i = 1,1000000
       write(out,*) ',Hello World'
    END DO

    call cpu_time(finish)
    print '("Time = ",f6.3," seconds.")',finish-start

  end program w

>gfortran -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -fcheck=all -fwhole-file w.f90
>./a.out 
Time =  0.272 seconds.
>./a.out 
Time =  0.260 seconds.
>./a.out 
Time =  0.244 seconds.
>
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am using [CPU_TIME](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CPU_005fTIME.html) to measure Fortran CPU.

> Returns a REAL value representing the elapsed CPU time in seconds.
>   This is useful for testing segments of code to determine execution
>   time.

Based on comment below. I redid the timing For fortran, I am only familiar with CPU_TIME. But Linux itself has the command [/usr/bin/time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) so this below measures the whole program timing from the shell itself.

```
program w
    integer :: i 
    integer, parameter :: out = 10
    open(out, file='writetest.csv', status='replace', action='write')
    DO i = 1,1000000
       write(out,*) ',Hello World'
    END DO
end program w
```

result

```
>gfortran -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -fcheck=all -fwhole-file w.f90
>time ./a.out 

real    0m0.523s    %this is total ELAPSED wall clock time
user    0m0.024s
sys         0m0.240s

>time ./a.out 

real    0m0.486s
user    0m0.048s
sys         0m0.200s

>time ./a.out 

real    0m0.502s
user    0m0.048s
sys         0m0.196s
```

So, the whole Fortran program took 0.5 seconds in wall clock time. Not much difference from earlier.

Mathematica [Timing](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Timing.html) is

> evaluates expr, and returns a list of the time in seconds used,
>   together with the result obtained

Mathematica [AbsoluteTiming](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html)

> evaluates expr, returning a list of the absolute number of seconds in
>   real time that have elapsed, together with the result obtained

and Matlab's [tic/toc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html).

> tic starts a stopwatch timer to measure performance. The function
>   records the internal time at execution of the tic command. Display the
>   elapsed time with the toc function.

If so, then Fortran is about 24 times faster than Mathematica and 38 times faster than Matlab.

Will try C++ later if I can or someone else can try.

Comment: I think absolute timing would be more appropriate here. I don't think I/O is counted under CPU time.

Comment: @Ajasja added version using `AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: use `time()` for the fortran test

Comment: @george2079 add timing using /usr/bin/time

Comment: How can one trust these comparison when they're done on different systems? Obviously hard drive speed can dramatically affect these timings.

Comment: @RunnyKine yes, sure, but they just give a general estimate I would think. This is all not a scientific performance study by any means. It is not meant to be. There are many variables involved and to do this right.

Comment: @Nasser, got it, thanks for doing the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

#### C++:

```cpp
 #include <fstream>
 main(){
 std::ofstream f("test.csv");
 for (int i=0;i<1000000;++i)f<<",Hello World\n";
 }
```

> /usr/bin/time: 0.03user .02 sys .06 elapsed

#### python:

```python
 f=open('test.csv','w')
 for i in range(1000000):f.write(',Hello World\n')
```

> .39 user .051 sys .44 elapsed

#### *Mathematica* as a command line kernel script:

```
 f=OpenWrite["test.csv"];
 Do[ WriteString[f,",Hello World"] ,{1000000}];
```

> /usr/bin/time math -scipt test.m
>
> 4.08 user 2.3 sys 7.3 elapsed

(about 1 sec elapsed without the `Do` loop, just start up and open the file)
Incidentally, If I put Timing[] around the loop it reports 5.68s so that seem consistent.

Comment: For C++, the I/O performance will depend much more on the libraries used and the particular implementation than on the language.  I remember that on Windows XP I used to get slight different results with `cstdio` and `iostream` using MinGW, significantly different results using MinGW and Visual Studio, and different results again on Linux on the computer.